# Test passing when it shouldn't shouldn't on conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Building a rails 4.2 app, and I'm fairly new to TDD, but I'm really working on learning it, and I can't figure out why the below test is passing.

```
def setup
    @lead = Lead.new(first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Blow", email: "joe@example.com", phone: "555 555 5555",
            number_of_rooms: 5)
end
...
...

test "should have origin state if origin country is United States" do
    @lead.origin_country_id = Country.create!(name: "United States").id
    @lead.origin_state_id = nil
    assert_not @lead.save
end
```

My model file is below:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :origin_country_id, presence: true
    validates :destination_country_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :origin_state, class_name: 'State', foreign_key: 'origin_state_id'
    belongs_to :destination_state, class_name: 'State', foreign_key: 'destination_state_id'
    belongs_to :origin_country, class_name: 'Country', foreign_key: 'origin_country_id'
    belongs_to :destination_country, class_name: 'Country', foreign_key: 'destination_country_id'
end
```

Like I said, I'm new to TDD, so if this is a bad test, please let me know how you would improve it.  Basically, this is used to quote people for shipping things internationally, so I have an origin country and destination country, and I need to validate that countries with states have the state field filled in when submitting data.  Country is a model with just a name, state is a model with with a country id and belongs to a country.

Answer (score 0):

You're validating the presence of `origin_country_id`, but not the presence of `origin_state_id`. In your test, you set the value of `origin_country_id`, but since you aren't validating `origin_state_id`, you're telling Rails `nil` is an acceptable value for that field.

Comment: so how can I isolate the origin country in my test so that it ensures that the state is present if the country is the United States?

Comment: It's not about isolating the country. You're not validating presence of state ID at all. You have 2 `validates` shown, neither of which are for `state`.